# Warning C4150 deletion of pointer to incomplete type when trying to wrap native c++ class

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to write a ref class template in C++/CLI that can be used to wrap a native C++ type based on the advice [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx). This is what I have so far:

```
template<class T>
public ref class NativeWrapper {
  T* ptr_;

protected:
  !NativeWrapper() { delete ptr_; }  // <-- C4150 Warning here!

public:
  NativeWrapper(std::unique_ptr<T> ptr) : ptr_(ptr.release()) {}

  T* get() { return ptr_; }
  T* operator->() { return ptr_; }

  ~NativeWrapper() { NativeWrapper::!NativeWrapper(); }
};
```

I then want to use it as a member in a ref class but I want to use a forward declaration for the native class in the .h file:

```
// MyManagedClass.h

#include "NativeWrapper.h"

// forward declaration
class MyNativeClass;

ref class MyManagedClass {
  NativeWrapper<MyNativeClass> my_native_class_;
public:
  MyManagedClass();
  void doSomething();
};

// MyManagedClass.cpp    

#include "MyManagedClass.h"
#include "MyNativeClass.h"

MyManagedClass::MyManagedClass() : my_native_class_(std::make_unique<MyNativeClass>()) { }

void MyManagedClass::doSomething() {
  my_native_class->doSomething();
}
```

The destructor of the native class seems to be called correctly but I get the following warning:

```
Warning C4150 deletion of pointer to incomplete type 'MyNativeClass'; no destructor called
```

See comment indicating the line above.

I've tried explicitly writing a destructor and a finalizer in `MyManagedClass.cpp` which is what I would do if I encountered a similar problem in native c++ but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: I believe  the destructor indeed cannot be called here. Your  design problem is that by forward declaring MyNativeClass you are trying to combine the  native wrapper with pimpl idiom, and pimpl idiom cannot be templated.

Comment: @Eugene isn't this wrapper akin to `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` which are templated and can be used in the pimpl idiom.

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered that if I make the member a handle rather than using stack semantics then I don't get the warning anymore:

```
// MyManagedClass.h

#include "NativeWrapper.h"

// forward declaration
class MyNativeClass;

ref class MyManagedClass {
  NativeWrapper<MyNativeClass>^ my_native_class_;
public:
  MyManagedClass();
  void doSomething();
};

// MyManagedClass.cpp    

#include "MyManagedClass.h"
#include "MyNativeClass.h"

MyManagedClass::MyManagedClass() 
: my_native_class_(gcnew NativeWrapper<MyNativeClass>((std::make_unique<MyNativeClass>())) { }

void MyManagedClass::doSomething() {
  my_native_class->doSomething();
}
```

So, I assume that is OK.

I'm not sure I understand entirely why though. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx) "when you create an instance of a reference type using stack semantics, the compiler does internally create the instance on the garbage collected heap (using gcnew)".